# How to Compress Large Files C#

Tags: c#, compression

I am using this method to compress files and it works great until I get to a file that is 2.4 GB then it gives me an overflow error:

```
 void CompressThis (string inFile, string compressedFileName)
 {

        FileStream sourceFile = File.OpenRead(inFile);
        FileStream destinationFile = File.Create(compressedFileName);


        byte[] buffer = new byte[sourceFile.Length];
        sourceFile.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);

        using (GZipStream output = new GZipStream(destinationFile,
            CompressionMode.Compress))
        {
            output.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
        }

        // Close the files.
        sourceFile.Close();
        destinationFile.Close();
  }
```

What can I do to compress huge files?

Comment: You're loading the whole file into memory, either reuse the FileStream and pass that to your compression library, or set a max buffer size, load in chunks and loop until you reach EOF.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should not to write the whole file to into the memory. Use [`Stream.CopyTo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.stream.copyto#System_IO_Stream_CopyTo_System_IO_Stream_) instead. This method reads the bytes from the current stream and writes them to another stream using a specified buffer size (81920 bytes by default).

Also you don't need to close `Stream` objects if use `using` keyword.

```
void CompressThis (string inFile, string compressedFileName)
{
    using (FileStream sourceFile = File.OpenRead(inFile))
    using (FileStream destinationFile = File.Create(compressedFileName))
    using (GZipStream output = new GZipStream(destinationFile, CompressionMode.Compress))
    {
        sourceFile.CopyTo(output);
    }
}
```

You can find a more complete example on [Microsoft Docs (formerly MSDN)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.compression.gzipstream#examples).

Answer (score 4):

You're trying to allocate all of this into memory. That just isn't necessary, you can feed the input stream directly into the output stream.

Comment: While this answer is correct, it _tells_ instead of _shows_ the author how to solve the problem. Give some sample code that shows how fix the problem.

Answer (score 3):

Alternative solution for ***zip*** format without allocating memory -

```
using (var sourceFileStream = new FileStream(this.GetFilePath(sourceFileName), FileMode.Open))
            {
                using (var destinationStream =
                    new FileStream(this.GetFilePath(zipFileName), FileMode.Create, FileAccess.ReadWrite))
                {
                    using (var archive = new ZipArchive(destinationStream, ZipArchiveMode.Create, true))
                    {
                        var file = archive.CreateEntry(sourceFileName, CompressionLevel.Optimal);
                        using (var entryStream = file.Open())
                        {
                            var fileStream = sourceFileStream;
                            await fileStream.CopyTo(entryStream);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

The solution will write directly from input stream to output stream